# SSH server when phone is sleeping: possible?

Tags: wi-fi, ssh, standby

I an running the Dropbear SSH server on CyanogenMod 7.2.  Is there any way to setup my phone so that I can connect to it over wifi even when it is in sleep mode?  I don't mind if there is a small hit on the battery.

If not, is there a way to at least allow an rsync over ssh to proceed after the screen blanks out?  The strange thing here is that if I initiate an ssh shell connection, the command line is still usable after the phone goes to sleep, however it is very slow (changing the CPU governor didn't seem to make a difference).  Rsync seems to freeze when the phone sleeps.

I tried `echo hello > /sys/power/wake_lock`, to no effect.

Comment: Have you setup your WiFi standby policy to keep it permanently on? Many devices automatically turn it off when the screen goes off. Check in *Settings->WiFi->Advanced* (via menu button), and set it accordingly if it's not.

Comment: @Izzy: Yes.  I set Wi-Fi sleep policy to Never.

Comment: OK, then I don't know. Might be worth trying a different SSH server app, though.